# Exclamation (You don't know how serious he can become)

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, adjectifs, exclamations

How do we tackle exclamation in French. In English we have two separate forms for noun and adjective

> How great the trip was !
>
> What a nice day !

In French it seems there is only one form

> 1. How beautiful today is !

Que il fait beau au aujourd'hui.

> 2. You don't know how serious he can become.

I would try with « Tu ne sais pas que il peut devenir sérieux ».

> 3. You can't imagine how much havocs he can cause.

No idea.

> 4. What a great trip!

Perhaps « Que il était un bon voyage ! » ?

Side question: Why don't we shorten « **Que il** fait beau » as « **Qu'il** fait beau ».
In some other cases I noticed that we dont abbreviate « que il » as « qu'il ».
What is the rule ?

#### Update following some recommendations for

> 3. You can't imagine how much havocs/chaos he can cause.

I noticed some responses for this sentence. Would the following means more or less the same thing :

> Tu n'imagines pas quel chaos qu'il peut causer.
>
> Tu n'imagines pas le chaos qu'il peut causer.
>
> Tu n'imagines pas à quel point il peut causer le chaos.
>
> Tu n'imagines pas tant de chaos qu'il peut causer.

Which is correct/has the closest meaning to the original sentence ? To me translation like « Tu n'imagines pas le chaos qu'il peut causer. » seems to miss the emphasis « how much chaos ». It means lighter « You can't image the chaos he can cause »

Comment: About your update, numbers 2 and 3 means more or less the same thing, even if there are slight differences. The first one is wrong (remove " qu' "), and the last one is wrong too ("tant" can't be used this way). You may add the emphasis you're looking for with "**tout** le chaos". Also, there is already an emphasis in the sentence « Tu n'imagines pas le chaos qu'il peut causer. », since "Tu n'impagines pas" is stressed, and "le chaos" is said more softly, which makes an emphasis.

Comment: I agree "You can't imagine" carry some emphasis meaning. How about if we remove the emphasis part of "Tu n'impagines pas" and replace by a lighter "Je ne sais pas", would the second part "le chaos qu'il peut causer" still carry so much emphasis ? Similar to English, " I did't know the chaos he can cause" and "I did't know that much chaos he can cause". The emphasis really stays on "that much" .

Comment: I think "**tout le** chaos qu'il peut causer" brings what you wish :)

Comment: you hae to shorten "que il" into "qu'il". Your French sentences look like word by word automatic translation and most are incorrect.

Comment: same with the "chaos" sentences. 1) tu n'imagines pas quel chaos il peut causer (no "qu'"), 4) tu n'imagines pas tout le chaos qu'il peut causer (not "tant")

Comment: My mistake, I meant "tant de chaos" with the meaning of "that much", "so much"

Comment: Propositions 2 and 3 are good. Proposition 1 and 4 are not correct. If you want to use *tant de* then you could say: Tu n'imaginais pas qu'il puisse causer tant de chaos. You couldn't imagine he would cause so much chaos. If using *quel*: Tu n'imagines pas quel chaos il peut causer (without *qu'il*).

Comment: Is "quel chaos QU'il peut causer" strictly wrong or QU is optional ? As in English "..the chaos he can cause" and "the chaos THAT he can cause", THAT is optional but not wrong if put. Same question for the other 3 sentences 1, 2 and 4 in the Update. Can we omit "qu" in "qu'il" ?

Comment: @Kenny In french, "que" is not optionnal as in english. You must or mustn't use it, you can't choose. In **s1**: you can't say "quel chaos qu'il". so "qu" is forbidden. In **s2**: you have to use "qu". In **s3**: you can't add "qu". In **s4**: with the correction from MrUpsidedown, you have to use "qu" (Tu n'imaginais pas qu'il puisse causer tant de chaos)

Comment: @Random : Can you give me some rules and/or reference as to when we must and must not use "que". I tend to think it is optional, which, from what you said, is a big mistake. In "Il y a 2 devoirs (que) tu dois faire", would "que" be required as well ?

Comment: @Kenny Indeed, "que" is also required here. I don't know the exact rule since it is natural for me, maybe someone knows more about it... I think the problem is that "que" may have different roles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jumping to exclamations like your examples #2 and #3, where you want include the notion of “you don’t know how/to what point …,” I’d used:

“Tu [ne] peux pas savoir/imaginer … comme (ou à quel point) … (#2)il peut devenir serieux/(#3)il peut poser des problèmes!/il peut foutre le bordel!”

Back to #1, I’d say “Qu’il fait beau!”  or « Qu’est-ce qu’il fait beau! » (I’m pretty sure that the « que il » would [nearly ?] always elide/contract to « qu’il » [because of ‘il’ starting with a vowel], whereas “que tu” [consonant] would not elide: “Que tu es belle/beau! ” or « Qu’est-ce que tu es beau/belle! »)

« LA GRAMMAIRE FLE POUR ÉTUDIANTS FINNOPHONES » covers pretty well French [Conjonctions ou locutions exclamatives](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/577.html), although I don’t see the use of « Quel/quelle » mentioned, which is what I would use to say your #4 « Quel voyage super. »

Comment: Lien très intéressant pour des expressions couramment employées, du style soutenu au style très familier.

Answer (score 7):

#### Main question

Actually, most of the examples you gave translate almost as is.

> How beautiful today is !
> Qu'il fait beau aujourd'hui !
>
> ---
>
> You don't know how serious he can become.
> Tu ne sais pas à quel point il peut être/devenir sérieux.
>
> ---
>
> You can't imagine how much havoc he can cause.
> Tu n'imagines pas les dégâts qu'il peut causer.
>
> ---
>
> What a great trip!
> Quel bon voyage !

#### Side question

You do shorten *que il* as *qu'il*, always. This is difficult to articulate otherwise. When you have a pronounced *e* before another vowel sound, it always disappears.

---

<sub>I suggest you don't accept this answer yet as it doesn't meet my own quality standards. Either somebody will give more explanation, or I'll come back.</sub>

Comment: On pourrait aussi dire : "*Comme* il fait beau aujourd'hui", et, "Quel voyage *grandiose*"('dithyrambique', ou familier *formidable*), ou encore  *Quel superbe voyage*, à la mode *Quel voyage super*... N.B. : pour bon il existe déjà good < great

Comment: @downvoter As always, I don't mind being downvoted, as long as you can explain what's wrong so that I can avoid making the same mistakes again next time.

Comment: Ce site demande de justifier les votes négatifs pour permettre aux rédacteurs d'améliorer et/ou de corriger leur réponse, pas pour manifester une humeur personnelle indéchiffrable.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'd first answer your side question: you **have to** shorten it. *Que il* is not correct. You have to use *Qu'il*.

So let me correct your different sentences:

1. Qu'il fait beau aujourd'hui !
2. Tu ne sais pas à quel point il peut devenir sérieux.
3. Tu ne peux pas imaginer le chaos* qu'il peut causer.
4. Quel beau voyage !

*I am not very sure of the meaning of *havocs* but you can probably translate it by *le chaos* or *la confusion* or *les dégats*.

Regarding sentence 2: *how serious* means *how much serious* which in French you would translate by *à quel point*. A closer English version would be *You don't know to what point (or to what extent) he can be serious*.

Answer (score 3):

Je traduirais par:

1. Qu'il fait beau aujourd'hui !
2. Tu ne sais pas à quel point il peut devenir sérieux.
3. Tu n'imagines pas tous les ravages qu'il peut provoquer.
4. Quel bon voyage !