# Translation of "How cold is it?"

Tags: questions

"How cold is it in Paris in December?"

Should the translation be

> Combien froid fait-il à Paris en décembre ?

or

> À quel point froid fait-il à Paris en décembre ?

or something else?

[This question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14882/exclamation-you-dont-know-how-serious-he-can-become) is similar but not quite the same.

Comment: I'd say: "C'est froid comment ?"

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Sometimes some people say it this way but it's really incorrect. The real way is: *À quel point fait-il froid à Paris en décembre*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Je dirais plutôt "*Quel froid il fait à Paris ?*", je ne trouve pas très naturel d'utiliser "à quel point". De manière générale je dirais même plutôt "*Il fait froid à Paris ?*", en espérant qu'on me réponde mieux quoi oui/non !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oui, disons que je parlais plutôt de la traduction la plus correcte (du peu que j'y ai réfléchi, du moins) du "how" pour questionner sur *l'intensité* de quelque chose (à quel point fait-il froid, à quel point as-tu mal, à quel point m'aimes-tu, etc.), pas forcément de celle la plus utilisée. J'utiliserais aussi "il fait froid ?", voire un horrible "il fait beaucoup froid ?".

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/how-would-i-ask-how-adjective-is-something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like to leave only a comment so I'll turn mine into an answer :

Most of the time in that case, I'll just say "*Il fait froid à Paris ?*" and the answer will often be about *how cold* it is and not just *if it's cold* or not.

And if you want to be really specific about *how*, my choice would be "*Quel froid il fait/fait-il à Paris ?*". I find the sentence "*À quel point fait-il froid...*" a little heavy and unnatural.

You can't say "*Combien froid fait-il ?*" but you can say "*Combien fait-il à Paris ?*", and the answer will be in degrees: "*Il fait 3°* "

Answer (score 2):

> À quel point fait-il froid à Paris en décembre ?

This is the best solution. As @SimonDéchamps said in his comment, you have to invert *froid* et *fait-il* from the sentence you wrote.

> Il fait froid comment, à Paris en décembre ?

I'd totally say this in an oral conversation but I think when writing it is better to use the first solution.

However *Combien froid fait-il à Paris en décembre ?* is not a good alternative.